# Embed Visitor/Listener Options in an ANTLR4 Grammar

Tags: antlr4

I want to enable/disable visitor/listener generation from the g4 file.

Is there a way to embed Visitor/Listener options in an ANTLR4 grammar? I'm looking for something like this:

```
grammar foo;

options {
    visitor=false;
    listener=false;
}

...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not inside the `options` block.

You can provide the `Tool`, which generates these classes, command line options to make sure these classes are not generated.

For example, you generate classes for your grammar `T` as follows:

```
java -cp antlr-4.4-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool T.g4
```

And to make sure no listener or visitor files are being generated, do this:

```
java -cp antlr-4.4-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool T.g4 -no-listener -no-visitor
```

For the record, these are ANTLR4's command line options:

```
$java -cp antlr-4.4-complete.jar org.antlr.v4.Tool

ANTLR Parser Generator  Version 4.4
 -o ___              specify output directory where all output is generated
 -lib ___            specify location of grammars, tokens files
 -atn                generate rule augmented transition network diagrams
 -encoding ___       specify grammar file encoding; e.g., euc-jp
 -message-format ___ specify output style for messages in antlr, gnu, vs2005
 -long-messages      show exception details when available for errors and warnings
 -listener           generate parse tree listener (default)
 -no-listener        don't generate parse tree listener
 -visitor            generate parse tree visitor
 -no-visitor         don't generate parse tree visitor (default)
 -package ___        specify a package/namespace for the generated code
 -depend             generate file dependencies
 -D<option>=value    set/override a grammar-level option
 -Werror             treat warnings as errors
 -XdbgST             launch StringTemplate visualizer on generated code
 -XdbgSTWait         wait for STViz to close before continuing
 -Xforce-atn         use the ATN simulator for all predictions
 -Xlog               dump lots of logging info to antlr-timestamp.log
```

Comment: The reason for this is generation of these classes is a property of the application and/or target language using the grammar, and completely independent of the grammar itself. The maven, ant, and msbuild integrations (at least) support specifying these options.